# Code behind control with MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have been asked to develop a dialog window in WPF which contains a map control (OnlineMapControl). The map control & associated business logic sits in code behind. I've built my control as a window and also written a simple view model.

The parent  view which fires the dialog is from a button command in it's view model. I know ideally we should be using an IDialogService or equivalent however the seniors have advised me to go with .showdialog() in the view model command method a la:

```
Public ShowChildDialogCommandAction()
{
  DialogViewModel dialogViewModel = NewDialogViewModel();
  DialogView dialogview = new DialogView(dialogViewModel);

  dialogView.ShowDialog();
}
```

This works fine, tight coupling aside. The problems arise when I'm trying to access properties on the child view code behind based map control. The dialogViewModel instance knows nothing of the OnlineMapControl therefore I find myself trying to chase a property value through all these classes with duplicated property names & getting into logical spaghetti in the DialogView code behind with `this.onlineMapControl.zoomLevel = this.dialogViewModel.zoomLevel` etc. Which just has a really bad code smell. How do you tackle a design akin to this whereby a complex control within a view is only accessible through code behind & keep the MVVM pattern intact?

Comment: It's quite hard to comment without any code that shows exactly what the problem is.  It sounds like your map control should expose various dependency properties for things like `ZoomLevel`, and then you just bind them to your `DialogViewModel` in `DialogView`.

Comment: mvvm != no codebehind. UI logic should go in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing proper MVVM then your view model should be the view's DataContext:

```
DialogViewModel dialogViewModel = NewDialogViewModel();
DialogView dialogview = new DialogView{DataContext = dialogViewModel};
```

From that point on the DialogView XAML should use data-binding and shouldn't have any code-behind itself, so copying any data between it and the DialogViewModel becomes a moot point.

Incidentally, a service isn't the only way to implement dialog boxes, it's quite easy to implement using regular data-binding as I showed in [an article I wrote last year](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM).